# Shiny checkFunc not triggering valueFunc

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building an dashboard to stay on a TV. No users sessions would be required and the deploy will be on a private server (not shiny.io). The main ideia is the dashboard update itself every 15 seconds.

My problem is in the server function, actually at `checkFun` and `valueFunc` of `reactivePoll()`.
Here is what I did:

- I created a function named `checkUpdateData()` that checks if the total income of the current month (variable `decFat` below) has increased. This functions prints a log on console showing the difference between old value and current value returned for `decFat`.
- I created a function named `getData()` that fetch a `JSON()` object from a `REST GET` call.
- I created a function named `etl(input = getData())` passing the `JSON` as an input parameter. This function makes all the ETL process and outputs a cleaned/treated `list()` object, with `data.frame`'s objects attached to it.

If `checkUpdateData()` return differences between `decFat` and previous `decFat`, then calls `valueFunc` of `reactivePoll()`, rigth?

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  pollData <- reactivePoll(
            intervalMillis = 15000,
            session = NULL,
            
            checkFunc = function() {
              checkUpdateData(ambiente = pAmbiente)
            },
            
            valueFunc = function() {

              etl(listObj = getData(ambiente = pAmbiente,
                                    dataI    = pDataI,
                                    dataF    = pDataF))  
        
              print("************************ check")

            }
          )

  output$dataReq <- renderTable({ pollData() })

  output$tabela <- renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(dataReq$tbRepresent %>%
                    filter(Mes == format(Sys.Date(), format="%m")) %>%
                    select(" " = emoji, "Rep" = Representante, "Fat" = Faturamento2, "Região" = Regiao, "% Met Bat." = percMetaBatida, "% Fat" = percFaturamento),
                  options = list(pageLength = 20, dom = ''), rownames = FALSE)
  })

  output$updateTime <- renderText(dataReq$updateTime$children[[1]] %>%
                                    as.character() %>%
                                    stringr::str_replace_all(., "\n", "") %>%
                                    stringr::str_replace_all(., "   ", " "))

}
```

The `print("***check")` never has printed when running.
Below the log when the App is running:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:567
13/11/2020 10:37:08
Last decFat: 9209947.53363352 | Previous decFat: 430074.858996368
13/11/2020 10:37:08
Last decFat: 9213301.07789995 | Previous decFat: 430074.858996368
13/11/2020 10:37:24
Last decFat: 9206235.81931037 | Previous decFat: 430074.858996368
```

I can't figure out how to force `dataReq` update itself.
Any thoughts would be very appreciated.

Thanks advance.

Comment: What does `checkUpdateData` *return*?

Comment: @r2evans It returns the current value for the `decFat`, decimal. On the log is the `Last decFat: 9209947.53363352` i.e.

Comment: printing something to a log and returning a value are two different things, the first does not imply the second. Also, does `etl` work entirely in side-effect? Are you intentionally calling it and discarding its return value? From the current code, `valueFunc` will always be either `NULL` (not yet called) or a string of `"*** check"`, and never anything else.

Comment: @r2evans I entended to print to log just to be sure. In the function `checkUpdateData()` I write `return(decFat)` to return to `checkFunc`. Also, the `elt()` works entirely in side-effect, and within it, I call `return(listObj)`. So do I have to discard the `*** check` in the `valueFunc` because it is replacing the returned `listObj` of `etl`?

Comment: Please make this question reproducible by including the relevant source of those functions. BTW: `elt` returning `listObj` does absolutely no good in your `valueFunc` unless you do something with its return value. As is, `return(listObj)` is doing absolutely nothing here.

Comment: Why do you pass NULL instead of session?

Comment: Good catch, @HubertL, that seems like a likely culprit.

Comment: Hi @ r2evans and @HubertL, sorry for the late. I were making a reproducible example when I realized another approach for my problem. Using `reactiveTimer ()` within `render`'s functions on `server` function made it work. Thank you very much for your time folks.